# Will vite work with react server components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, react-server-components

Since RSC(React Server Components) is using server + client components with a `use client` keyword to split them out from each other.
I was wondering how vite will behave. How it will work there?
I know that vite has SSR support with some built-in features.
But about RSC I am wondering how it will happen.

Comment: It's in progress, check out https://github.com/nksaraf/fully-react, https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4591, https://github.com/dai-shi/wakuwork/issues/21, https://github.com/rakkasjs/rakkasjs/issues/38